# JasperReports: Creating a Watermark with the Background Band

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to figure our how to set up a water mark for my JasperReport using pure Java (programmatically constructing the `JasperDesign` myself).

Say I have an image file for my watermark like so:

```
String imageFileUri = "/some/url/MyWatermark.jpg";
```

Now I want to add a **background band** to my `JasperDesign` that will overlay the `MyWatermark.jpg` image over every page of my report. I have a few lines of "start code" but am drawing a blank after that. I've searched high and low for code examples but can't find any.

```
JRDesignBand backgroundBand = new JRDesignBand();
backgroundBand.setHeight(842);
backgroundBand.setWidth(595);

// ...???
```

Thanks in advance for any clarity here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For solving this issue we can use [JRDesignImage](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignImage.html) element located in `Background Band`.

The sample:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign();

//Some code to filling bands .....

JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
band.setHeight(200);

//The expression must contain the double quotes!!! 
//This is a analogue of <imageExpression><![CDATA["watermark.png"]]></imageExpression>
String imgPath = "\"watermark.png\"";

JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setText(imgPath);

JRDesignImage image = new JRDesignImage(jasperDesign);
image.setX(45);
image.setY(55);
image.setWidth(165);
image.setHeight(40);
//We can use another scaling mode
image.setScaleImage(ScaleImageEnum.FILL_FRAME);
image.setExpression(expression);

//Adds image to the band
band.addElement(image);

//Adds band as background 
jasperDesign.setBackground(band);
```

Comment: Magnificent! Thank you very much!